# virsh-install partitioning auto-lvm confirmation fails

Tags: server

The lines in my preseed.cfg pertaining to partitioning are these:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/vda
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman/default_filesystem string xfs
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make the installer accept my config and move on.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The below block of syntax worked. Now I need to sort and diff to see wth was missing.

```
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman/default_filesystem string xfs
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/vda
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg00
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```